# How can I snap a duplicated part of a mesh to a hole with the exact size so it forms one whole object again?

Tags: mesh

I am still very much new to Blender, and I've been struggling with this problem for a couple of hours now. It might have been better if i'd just created another project from scratch at this point, but I want to see it through to the end and learn more in the process. Scouring the internet hasn't helped much.

I've been following a tutorial on modeling and composition and made a tea pot. All was fine and dandy until i started working on its handle. After much fiddling I was dissatisfied with the results and decided to delete the handle altogether. This left me with the following situation:

[image: gaping hole in teapot]

Since it is a round and symmetrical object, my first instinct was to duplicate the corresponding 3x4 side of the pot and just replace the old faces. That's where I got stuck - no matter how i try to snap to the remaining vertices / faces, the duplicated part always becomes deformed since there is nowhere i can snap the middle 2 faces to:

[image: the faulty faces]

So, is there any kind of way for me to bring this pot back into its original shape, or do I need to start over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the only transformation applied on the separate mesh was a translation (not rotation and not scale) you can easily wield the two pieces with some snapping.

Click on the magnet icon to enable snapping ,set the snapping mode to *vertex* and snapping target to *active*  :
[image]

[image]

The vertex encercled in red is the last selected vertex and the active one and is what the snap tool work with, to mark a vertex as active; deselect that vertex and reselect it so it's the last one selected.

with <kbd>G</kbd> to grab simply hover on the vertex (inside the green circle) where the two mesh parts should meet , the active vertex will snap to any vertex you hover your mouse on.
don't forget to remove doubles or enable automatic vertex merging.

Comment: This was very helpful! I did have to rotate and tinker with the piece i wanted to snap, but in the end this solution was closer to what I needed, so thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10):

Try to use a ***Grid Fill*** option. First select all edges around the hole with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>, then press <kbd>Space</kbd> and type ***Grid Fill***. If the result isn't as nice as you expected, change it's settings in a Tool Shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>).
[image]

Comment: I can see how this is great in a similar situation, but after having applied it on the pot i tampered with, the grid became rally warped. The other proposed solution was closer to my specific problem, even though both are right.